# In MDX, how can I perform a calculation on the child members and THEN aggregate those children?

Tags: mdx, olap

I have data like the table below, where Expected Shipment Amount New is effectively the average shipment amount per claim count, but I can't get that to aggregate correctly (it should be `26.3` total, not `0`). Does anyone have any idea how this could be done?

```
CliID | Claim Count | Expected Shipment Amount | CliId Count   Expected Shipment Amount New
All   |      5      |           61.8           |       2     |              0
159061|   (null)    |          (null)          |    (null)   |            (null)
159063|   (null)    |          (null)          |    (null)   |            (null)
166759|      2      |           34.2           |      1      |             17.1
166769|   (null)    |          (null)          |    (null)   |            (null)
223983|      3      |           27.6           |      1      |             9.2
```

This pre member is supposed to calculate the average for each individual CliID, and return null if there is no Expected Shipment Amount:

`CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount Pre]
 AS IIf(IsLeaf([Claim].[CliID].currentmember),
       ([Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount]/[Measures].[Claim Count]),0),
 VISIBLE = 0;`

And then this is what should be visible so that everything is aggregated correctly:

`CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount New]
 AS SUM([Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount Pre]),
 VISIBLE=1;`

It's pretty clear that at the aggregate level it is looking at `Expected Shipment Amount Pre` and returning `0` since the aggregate itself isn't a leaf, but for the aggregate I'd like it to calculate all the children and then add them up. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried making `[Expected Shipment Amount Pre]` visible and then querying the cube?

Comment: Yes, but what does that show me? In the aggregate level (All), it shows zero as `[Expected Shipment Amount Pre]` and that's because we're not at a leaf there. I want it to sum up the children when we're not at a leaf, if that makes sense.

Comment: ok - I'm starting to understand your requirement - is `26.3` definitely correct as `61.8 / 5 <> 26.3`?

Comment: Yes because `9.2 + 17.1 = 26.3`

Comment: I'm interested in all the `MDX` tagged questions. Apologies that I couldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

In your second step, you should use

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount New]
 AS SUM(EXISTING [Claim].[CliID].[CliID].Members, [Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount Pre]),
VISIBLE=1;
```

i. e. sum across the members of the members of the `CliID` level.

**EDIT**
Something you could try to speed this up is to rely more on the built in Analysis Services aggregation. To do this, create a **physical measure** `Expected Shipment Amount New` based on the `Expected Shipment Amount` column in the fact table, and set its aggregation function to ``sum`. Then, in the calculation script, just add

```
SCOPE([Claim].[CliID].[CliID].Members);
    [Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount New] = [Measures].[Expected Shipment Amount] / [Measures].[Claim Count];
END SCOPE;
```

This will overwrite the calculation of 'Expected Shipment Amount New' on leaf level with the average calculation, but not state anything about the `All` level of the `CliID` attribute hierarchy. Hence, for this level, the specified aggregation of the measure, which is `sum`, should take place.

Comment: Cool. This seems to be slowing down the query dramatically though. Is that to be expected/is there anyway to expedite this?

Comment: @Travis `EXISTING` can cause a hefty slowdown. You could get rid of the `IIf` in you first statement, as the second one takes care that you always are on leaf level if you use the measure, and no user could use the measure, as it is invisible. Thus, the calculation may get a bit simpler and thus faster.